# What is the concept (or idea) behind "induced subgraph" definition?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G, G'$ be graphs.

If $G' \subseteq G$ and $G'$ contains *all* the edges $xy \in E$ with $x,y \in V'$, then $G'$ is an **induced subgraph** of $G$. We say that $V'$ **induces** or spans $G'$ in $G$, and write $G'=:G[V']$. Thus if $U \subseteq V$ is any set of vertices, then $G[U]$ denotes the graph on $U$ whose edges are precisely the edges of $G$ with both ends in $U$.

Can I say that the term "induced" brings some sort of equivalence meaning? So that, if some equivalence holds, I can use smaller structures for my convenience. 
In other words, does the graph $G'$ preserve some sort of structure or properties belonging to graph $G$?

Comment: The graph $G'$ inherets all edges of $G$ that exist between nodes of $G'$.

Comment: The reason it's called "induced" is that you don't select which edges go into $G'$: once you select which vertices are included in $G'$ then the edges are **induced** from the selected vertices.  There is no deeper meaning beyond that, so you shouldn't assume that a particular property is preserved by the operation unless there is a good reason for it.  But it would be reasonable to say something like "a vertex colouring of $G$ induces a colouring of $G'$".

Comment: thanks @ErickWong your comment let me understand what "induced" means.

Comment: So, "induced" also means that the choise (or construction) of an induced subgraph is more "restrictive" than a "normal subgraph" because the choise of the edges of the induced subgraph is not (totally) arbitrary because it depends on the choise of the vertex subset.